Unable to find $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} n^2 \varphi'(nx) f(x) \, dx $
Let $$
\varphi(x) = \frac{15}{16}(x^2 - 1)^2 \quad \text{for} \ |x| < 1, \quad \varphi(x) = 0 \quad \text{otherwise}.
$$
Let $f$ be a function with a continuous derivative. Find the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} n^2 \varphi'(nx) f(x) \, dx.
$$
Now, to solve this question my first approach was to see that use partial integration and get the following
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ f(x) \left( \frac{15}{16} n^3 x^2 \left( (nx)^2 - 2 \right) \right) - \int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{15}{16} n^3 x^2 \left( (nx)^2 - 2 \right) \right) f'(x) \, dx \right].$$
However, this does not serve me any purpose as the function alongside $f'(x)$ still does not form a positive summation kernel. Additionally, I do notice that $\varphi(x)$ is positive in the domain and its integral is equal to one, so I know there involves some clever manipulation where I can generate a sequence of functions that form a positive summation kernel and solve it.
Can anyone please help me solve the problem or let me know in which direction I should head towards.

First, let us take $u = nx, du = n dx$, so
so we get $$\int_{-n}^{n} n \varphi'(u) f(\frac{u}{n}) \, du.$$
Integrating by parts gives $$I_n = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\varphi(u)f'(\frac{u}{n})}{n} \, du. \textbf{ ERROR, look carefully, where?}$$
Now we have that $f'$ is continuous on a compact domain hence it achieves a minimum and a maximum, so by squeeze we obtain $$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = 0$$
Edit: I would like to come back to this question as it has come to my notice that I made a mistake and it surprised me nobody noticed. As the OP has stated we can use an argument similar to the Positive Summation Kernel because on the bounds $(-1,1)$ $\varphi(x)$ integrates to 1. Now we notice that integration by parts was supposed to give us: $$I_n = -\int_{-1}^{1} \varphi(u)f'(\frac{u}{n}) \, du = -f'(\frac{0}{n}) = -f'(0)$$
$\textbf{Hence the correct asnwer is:}$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = -f'(0).$$ For the fun of it, we can plug in some values in wolfram alpha and we see that it works, as it should :)
